# Error Training Vertex AI with Auto ML - Found time series with more than 3000 time steps. Ensure the lengths of all time series do not exceed 3000

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, automl, google-cloud-automl

Has anyone experienced this error while using Auto ML to train a model in Vertex AI? I don't understand what it means.

The time series I'm using has this format, "2021-06-24 00:00:00 UTC", and the error says:

> Found time series with more than 3000 time steps. Ensure the lengths of all time series do not exceed 3000.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6oVY.png)

Use Vertex Auto ML to train a model, using a data set from Big Query

- AutoML
- Tabular data set in Big query
- Previsión
- Optimized for RMSE

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Sebastian!

This error means that one of your timeseries (let's say at least one of the products on your dataset) has more than 3000 data points (hourly/daily entries).

An example - If I have the following dataset:

```
product, timestamp, count
1, 20230101, 1
1, 20230101, 5
1, 20230101, 2
1, 20230101, 3
1, 20230101, 4
2, 20230101, 6
2, 20230101, 8
2, 20230101, 5
2, 20230101, 1
3, 20230101, 2
3, 20230101, 3
3, 20230101, 4
```

The timeseries for the product `1` has 5 samples, `2` has 4 samples and `3` has 3 samples.

If you have any individual product/id with more than 3000 samples, you may face the error you are facing.